# Exception when trying to configure NServiceBus to use NHibernate persistence

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nservicebus, topshelf, nservicebus5

I am trying to make a few endpoints use NHibernate persistence, after using in-memory persistence for development. I am using the latest Nuget packages.

Right off the bat I get the following exceptions. It mentioned Topshelf upon which NServiceBus.Host is based, but I have no idea why.

**Please note: I don't get any errors at all using in-memory persistence.**

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   NServiceBus.NHibernate.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' in NServiceBus.Host.exe Exception
>   thrown: 'Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachineException' in
>   NServiceBus.Host.exe Additional information: Exception occurred in
>   Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1[[NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost,
>   NServiceBus.Host, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c]] during state Initial while handling
>   OnStart
>
> Exception thrown: 'Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachineException' in
>   NServiceBus.Host.exe Additional information: Exception occurred in
>   Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1[[NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost,
>   NServiceBus.Host, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c]] during state Initial while handling
>   OnStart
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: No NHibernate
>   properties found in your config file
>   (E:\Projects.........\MyEndpoint.dll.config).
>
> To run NServiceBus with NHibernate you need to at least specify the
>   database connectionstring. Here is an example of what is required:
>
> ```
> <!-- other optional settings examples -->
> <add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
> <add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/connection.driver_class"
> ```
>
> value="NHibernate.Driver.Sql2008ClientDriver"/>
>
> ```
> <!-- Optional overrides per persister -->
> <add name="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/Timeout" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial
> ```
>
> Catalog=timeout;Integrated Security=True" />

The [documentation](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/nhibernate/) doesn't say these settings are mandatory in the app.config of every endpoint.
**I want to configure this exclusively in code. Is that even possible?**

This is my NH configuration, for which I have created an empty SqlServer 2014 database called "nservicebus":

```
    config.EnableInstallers();

    var nhConfig = new Configuration
    {
        Properties =
        {
            ["dialect"] = "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect",
            ["connection.provider"] = "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider",
            ["connection.driver_class"] = "NHibernate.Driver.Sql2012ClientDriver"
        }
    };

    config.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>().UseConfiguration( nhConfig );
....
```

What am I missing? The documentation makes it sound simple, but it's not.

EDIT

What made this work was to do it this way:

```
        config.EnableInstallers();

        //OLD, didn't work
        //var nhConfig = new Configuration
        //{
        //    Properties =
        //    {
        //        ["dialect"] = "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect",
        //        ["connection.provider"] = "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider",
        //        ["connection.driver_class"] = "NHibernate.Driver.Sql2012ClientDriver"
        //    }
        //};

        var nhConfiguration = new Configuration();
        nhConfiguration.SetProperty( NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionProvider, "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" );
        nhConfiguration.SetProperty( NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, "NHibernate.Driver.Sql2008ClientDriver" );
        nhConfiguration.SetProperty( NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect" );
        nhConfiguration.SetProperty( NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionStringName, "NServiceBus/Persistence" );

        config.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>().UseConfiguration( nhConfiguration );
```

The MsSql2008Dialect also works with Sql 2012, 2014.

What remains in the app.config is the connection string, which I need for Entity Framework anyway.

But, as @DavidBoike mentions below, you can also take that out of the app.config and configure it programatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the connection string pretty easily in code:

```
busConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>()
    .ConnectionString("your-connection-string-here");
```

You do need to include the `NServiceBus.Persistence` namespace for the extension method to be available.

You are right that the [NHibernate Persistence](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/nhibernate/) documentation page does not cover simply setting the connection string very well. I've [opened a GitHub issue on the docs repository](https://github.com/Particular/docs.particular.net/issues/928) to track this.